# Core Plot binding to Core Data using NSArrayController crashed

Tags: core-data, core-plot, nsarraycontroller

I am trying to graph data in core data using core plot and bindings.
My Core Data model:

[image]

I am able to insert, so I know my contact is good... but this bombs at the binding with:

```
[<NSArrayController 0x6000001c40b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key measuredate.

-(void)addPlotWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier context:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
{

    CPTScatterPlot *newPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:graph.bounds];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier     = identifier;



    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth              = 2.0;
    lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor greenColor];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;


    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1380243600)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1382835600)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                     length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(100)];

    [dataSourceLinePlot setPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    NSLog(@"Create a controller");
    NSArrayController *newController=[[NSArrayController alloc] initWithContent:nil];
    NSLog(@"MOC: set context");
    [newController setManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSLog(@"MOC: set Entity");
    [newController setEntityName:@"BM_Measure"];
    NSLog(@"MOC: set Editable");
    [newController setEditable:FALSE];
    NSLog(@"MOC: set sort descriptors");
    [newController setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"measuredate" ascending:YES]]];
    NSLog(@"MOC: fetch");

    [newController setAutomaticallyPreparesContent:TRUE];
    [newController setAutomaticallyRearrangesObjects:TRUE];
    NSError *error;
    if ([newController  fetchWithRequest:nil merge:NO error:&error] == NO){
        NSLog(@"Couldnt fetch");
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",newController);

    NSLog(@"Bind x");
    [newPlot bind:CPTScatterPlotBindingXValues toObject:newController withKeyPath:@"measuredate" options:nil];
    NSLog(@"Bind y");
    [newPlot bind:CPTScatterPlotBindingYValues toObject:newController withKeyPath:@"measurevalue" options:nil];
    NSLog(@"Save Objects");

    [g_Plots addObject:newPlot];
    [g_ArrayControllers addObject:newController];
    [graph addPlot:newPlot];
    NSLog(@"Added... %ld",[g_Plots count]);



}
```

Comment: should your binding be to `newController.arrangedObjects` ?

Answer (score 0):

Core Plot binding expect arrays of data. This is the bindings code from the *CPTTestApp* example app:

```
[boundLinePlot bind:CPTScatterPlotBindingXValues
           toObject:self 
        withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.x"
            options:nil];
[boundLinePlot bind:CPTScatterPlotBindingYValues
           toObject:self
        withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.y"
            options:nil];
```

Comment: SO you are saying it does not work with CoreData? I'd have to extract core data info into NSArrays?

Comment: I suppose more to the point, any examples of Core Plot using Core Data source to plat graphs anywhere?

Comment: @JeremyLaurenson: you can also implement the datasource methods instead and query your coredata storage for values there. Not the same as bindings but works as well. Ah yes, you could of course implement a small NSController object that does this but is bindable.